# PHP/AJAX BASH Gaining Access To API SYSTEM

Tags: php, ajax, bash, curl

Im having a hard time understanding the tutorial for the API [of this site](https://jsonodds.com/documentation#test-data), you can see the first part of the tutorial uses a BASH command line script for GAINING ACCESS

[image]

When I run the above curl command in the BASH commandline I get the output of everything the API offers

[image]

### MY QUESTION

How do I gain access to the API ***without the BASH command line***, by only unsing an AJAX / PHP script? What am I not understanding here?

EDIT:

**I have tried:**

```
<?php
$output = shell_exec('curl -X GET https://jsonodds.com/api/odds -H "JsonOdds-API-Key: xxxxxxxx"');
echo "<pre>".$output."</pre>";
?>
```

My most recent attempt included an attempt as per suggestion from user @v7d8dpo4

```
$api_key = "yourapikey";
$ch = curl_init("https://jsonodds.com/api/odds?source=3");
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("JsonOdds-API-Key: " . $api_key),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Doing a vardump on `$response` gives me `var_dump($response); = bool(false)`

Doing a vardump on `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch))` gives me  `= array(26) { ["url"]=> string(38) "https://jsonodds.com/api/odds?source=3" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(0) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0)`

**I am simply looking for a way to connect to the API, but despite numerous attempts I cant connect**

Comment: Are you asking how to make an HTTP request in JavaScript or PHP? Surely that's what a search engine is for.

Comment: Have you actually tried anything yet?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson please see update of what I have tried

Comment: 1. Don't use `shell_exec()`. You can do this in pure PHP. 2. The `-H` switch before `JsonOdds-API-Key:xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx` in the curl-example indicates that it is a header. You need to add `JsonOdds-API-Key` as a header to your curl call, with `xxxxx-xxxxx-xxxx` as the value. It should not be in the URL.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson THANK YOU I believe I am slowly getting there...one question if you dont mind what do I do with  the `-d source=3` part...?

Answer (score 1):

Like this.

```
$api_key = "yourapikey";
$ch = curl_init("https://jsonodds.com/api/odds?source=3");
curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
    CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array("JsonOdds-API-Key: " . $api_key),
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Comment: Thank you sooo much for your input and helpfull answer I am getting no output can this be because I am testing on localhost?

Comment: P.s curl is enabled I double checked in phpinfo()

Comment: @Marilee The response from server is returned from `curl_exec($ch);`.

Comment: Thank you for your ongoing help...since I am getting no output....what do you suggest I do...?

Comment: would you mind if I inbox you my API key and you can see for yourself...? Why did you add `$response`? I tried to `echo` it but still nothing...can I send you my key?

Comment: @Marilee What does `var_dump($response);` give you? What does stderr say? What does `var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch));` give you?

Comment: Hi and THANK YOU SO MUCH FOR YOUR ONGOING HELP below follows `var_dump` results `var_dump($response); = bool(false)`

Comment: var_dump(curl_getinfo($ch)) = `array(26) { ["url"]=> string(38) "https://jsonodds.com/api/odds?source=3" ["content_type"]=> NULL ["http_code"]=> int(0) ["header_size"]=> int(0) ["request_size"]=> int(0) ["filetime"]=> int(0) ["ssl_verify_result"]=> int(0) ["redirect_count"]=> int(0)`

Answer (score 0):

A NULL response for an "https" curl operation in PHP usually means that you don't have your certificate chain set correctly for SSL.

You can verify by adding

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

before the curl_exec.

This tells curl to ignore certificate errors: it is "dangerous" (for want of a better word), so only used for debugging.

If this shows that it is the error, then you can fix by either adding suitable certificates to you chain, or pointing curl (through another option) to a local certificate. If depends on your system and set up. More information on it here: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html